# Is The Online Version of La Guerre des Moutons Identical To the "Real" Game?

Tags: online

I've been playing La Guerre des Moutons (aka Wooly Bully?) at boiteajeux.net and I have to say I'm all at sea.

It's a tile placement game very reminiscent of Carcassonne, but in boiteajeux's implementation I can't see any way of rotating a tile - as far as I can tell you have to fit the tile onto the map in the same orientation that it's presented to you.

I just don't see how, in the "real" game, the tiles wouldn't be rotatable.  Additionally, in the online implementation the tiles appear to be two-sided - this is obviously difficult to represent, but the tiles are presented to you as connected pairs, and if you play the top half of the pair A, you lose the option to play B.  Again I find it difficult to believe the tiles are two-sided in the "real" game, because then it'd be a nightmare to keep your hidden information secret from the other players.

Can anyone who has played this game in real life describe to me how it works?  Is the boiteajeux version a creative adaptation of the original game for online play, or have I just spectacularly failed to comprehend what's going on here?

EDIT: And, d'oh, I've just worked out how to rotate tiles in the online game before playing them.  Feeling a bit silly now for playing a couple of games with a serious self-handicap!  I'd still like to hear any answers that can tell me how/if online Wooly Bully differs from offline play; as I still don't understand if the tiles are double-faced or not... Amending question title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a great fan of this game, I can tell you that **yes**, the tiles are double-sided. You pick them from a bag, so you can't see anything and you put them in the palm of your had, as described in the rules: [image: How to hold tiles in "La Guerre des moutons"]

Using this technique, you can easly hide all the tiles from your opponnents.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks!  I started to "get" the rules of online Guerre des Moutons eventually, but this has helped me visualise what's going on in the real game... answer accepted!